# How to configure Apache Kafka with SSL in Presto

Tags: apache-kafka, presto

I am trying to configure Presto to read data from Apache Kafka. kafka clusters are running on SSL protocol and would like to know how to configure ssl protocol, truststore.location and truststore.password in kafka.properties file?

`connector.name=kafka
kafka.nodes=abc1:9092,abc2:9092, abc3:9092
kafka.table-names=customer
kafka.hide-internal-columns=false`

I tried adding

`kafka.consumer-key=/Users/presto/kafka.truststore.jks
kafka.consumer-secret=a1b2c3`

however, it is failing

ERROR   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Configuration property 'kafka.consumer-key' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:233)

2) Configuration property 'kafka.consumer-secret' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:233)

2 errors
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Configuration property 'kafka.consumer-key' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:233)

2) Configuration property 'kafka.consumer-secret' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:233)

2 errors
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:543)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:159)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:240)
    at com.facebook.presto.kafka.KafkaConnectorFactory.create(KafkaConnectorFactory.java:87)
    at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnector(ConnectorManager.java:352)
    at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.addCatalogConnector(ConnectorManager.java:216)
    at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnection(ConnectorManager.java:208)
    at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnection(ConnectorManager.java:194)
    at com.facebook.presto.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalog(StaticCatalogStore.java:96)
    at com.facebook.presto.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalogs(StaticCatalogStore.java:74)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.run(PrestoServer.java:131)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.main(PrestoServer.java:73)

Comment: comsumer-key option is not exist in Presto I think. check the [manual](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/connector/kafka-tutorial.html)

Comment: That is correct. The manual document doesn't have any details on how to connect to Kafka SSL protocol.

Comment: Can anyone please provide some insights? we'd really appreciate it